# Capitalize names of a company's departments?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

My understanding is that if the term *department*, *unit*, etc. is omitted, the name of a company's department becomes a proper noun and hence is capitalized:

> Lisa works in the marketing department.
>
> Lisa from **Marketing** called. She is waiting for **Accounting** to approve her project.

Is this correct?

Comment: Mark from Linguistics called. He said he checked it with Proofreading, and it's OK to capitalize the company departments’ names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is common usage.